# Quartic equation in two variables with non-integer coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am trying to solve an equation of the type:
$\phi= a + b\cdot T_c^4 + c\cdot T_p^4$. The background is that this equation is related to the Stefan-Boltzmann radiation heat transfer equation.  Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Out here, we use MathJax to format our mathematical equations, in order to make them more readable. So, it will be beneficial to you to learn to format your equations using it. Here's a good tutorial to learn - https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020

Comment: What variable are you trying to solve for?

Comment: I am trying to establish a relation between T_p and T_c. These represent 'plate temperature'  and 'cover temperature'. What I have tried is to set phi (heat flux) constant at a reasonable value, choose a value for T_p and solve for T_c. The context is that this problem relates to finding the amount of heat absorbed in a plastic cover which covers a solar air heater. T_p is the temperature of the absorbing plate (metal such as steel). The full formula involves a lot of constants related to material absorptivity and reflectivity. I have pasted it in below with the link to a research paper.

Comment: Link:   http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.474.3665&rep=rep1&type=pdf